# in dialog box set view insert drawable image how can set in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

i am implementing  puzzle game application in this application create one button in click the button  display  original image of the puzzle .original image display in dialog box  then click ok  return in to actual page  how can implemented

```
bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),mThumbIds[GameActivity.level]);
```

please  forward some solution  its urgent this issue pending more days  thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set a icon in dialog box.
If so you can do it by the following

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Message");
    builder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.your_image);      
    alert.show();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set image in dialog box, this is a rough answer:

ImageView image=new ImageVIew(this);
image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(your width, height));

Set the background image on this imageview either by using drawable or by setting bitmap

new AlertDialog().Builder(this).setView(image).show();
This is just a rough solution, but it will give you an idea